# Error: Member not found: 'BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized' when running flutter Web App

Tags: flutter

I use isolates to improve my app's performance, I know that the web doesn't support using isolates, so I've created separate implementations for mobile and web, and the web doesn't have any code that is related to isolates, but I can't still get build

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new Flutter project that supports both mobile and web
- Add this code to the project: if `(!kIsWeb) { BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(RootIsolateToken.instance!);  }`

Expected results:

I should able to get build because I'm sure my Flutter web app doesn't have any isolate code in runtime
Actual results

Build error for web (not runtime even!)

`lib/utils/isolates.dart:86:40: Error: Member not found: 'BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized'. BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(args[1]!);`

Failed to compile the application.

Code:

`if (!kIsWeb) { BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(args[2]!); }`